# web scrapping: Why does it return a null value, Maybe a Java script issue?

Tags: python, web-scraping, discord.py

ok, so I'm new to web scraping. I followed a tutorial I found on the internet and it works a treat for a specific website. so I tried to change it up to work for another site.
I think I have figured out the headers as I get a 200 response, But when I'm targeting a div to pull its value I am just met with null. So my question is am I doing something wrong here? I have tried to follow other tuts to see if it would answer my question, But I guess because I am new I'm not really sure what to look for?!

**EDIT:**
I should be a bit more specific. so as you can see in my code, I am trying to scrape data from Chaos cards website, I think I have the search function sorted (could be wrong?) but what I'm trying to achieve is when I inspect the page I would like to take the data from

`<div class="product-detail__content">Out of stock </div>`
Specifically the "Out of stock" part. as I know this div will contain "in stock" assuming it is. But when I target this div I am just met with null

All I am trying to do is set up a scrapper that when a user in discord types a specific product it will search the website, if it is in stock or not, it will return saying in stock or not in stock. But for now I'm trying to take baby steps, and just get it to firstly print the data I'm after

**CODE**

```
import os
import asyncio
import discord
import bs4 as bs
import requests



r = requests.session()
client = discord.Client()


headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Safari/537.36 Edg/97.0.1072.76'}


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user.name} - Have a good day <3')
result = requests.get ("https://www.chaoscards.co.uk/", headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Safari/537.36 Edg/97.0.1072.76'})
print(result.status_code)


def site_search(keyword):
    resp = r.get(f'https://www.chaoscards.co.uk/prod/{keyword}', headers = headers)
    
    # print(resp.text)
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml')
    in_stock =''
    out_of_stock =''
    for x in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'product-detail__content'}): 
        if ' Out of stock ' in (x):
            in_stock = 'Out of stock bro'
        if ' In stock ' in str():
            out_of_stock  = 'Its in stock '           
    #current_image_url = soup.find('img', {'itemprop': 'image'}).get('src') #
    #current_name = soup.find('p', {'class': 'listing-title'}).get_text() 
    return in_stock,out_of_stock

@client.event
async def on_message(message):

   
    if message.content.startswith('.sm'):
         keyword = message.content.split('.sm')[1]
         
         print(site_search(keyword))
         in_stock,out_of_stock =  site_search(keyword)
```

**EDIT 2:**
So i printed the text from `resp = r.get(f'https://www.chaoscards.co.uk/prod/{keyword}', headers = headers)`
And received this in return

`````
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1" />
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
  <title>Just a moment...</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    html, body {width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
    body {background-color: #ffffff; color: #000000; font-family:-apple-system, system-ui, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, "Helvetica Neue",Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.7em;-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;}
    h1 { text-align: center; font-weight:700; margin: 16px 0; font-size: 32px; color:#000000; line-height: 1.25;}
    p {font-size: 20px; font-weight: 400; margin: 8px 0;}
    p, .attribution, {text-align: center;}
    #spinner {margin: 0 auto 30px auto; display: block;}
    .attribution {margin-top: 32px;}
    @keyframes fader     { 0% {opacity: 0.2;} 50% {opacity: 1.0;} 100% {opacity: 0.2;} }
    @-webkit-keyframes fader { 0% {opacity: 0.2;} 50% {opacity: 1.0;} 100% {opacity: 0.2;} }
    #cf-bubbles > .bubbles { animation: fader 1.6s infinite;}
    #cf-bubbles > .bubbles:nth-child(2) { animation-delay: .2s;}
    #cf-bubbles > .bubbles:nth-child(3) { animation-delay: .4s;}
    .bubbles { background-color: #f58220; width:20px; height: 20px; margin:2px; border-radius:100%; display:inline-block; }
    a { color: #2c7cb0; text-decoration: none; -moz-transition: color 0.15s ease; -o-transition: color 0.15s ease; -webkit-transition: color 0.15s ease; transition: color 0.15s ease; }
    a:hover{color: #f4a15d}
    .attribution{font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.5;}
    .ray_id{display: block; margin-top: 8px;}
    #cf-wrapper #challenge-form { padding-top:25px; padding-bottom:25px; }
    #cf-hcaptcha-container { text-align:center;}
    #cf-hcaptcha-container iframe { display: inline-block;}
  </style>

      <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="35">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    (function(){
      
      window._cf_chl_opt={
        cvId: "2",
        cType: "non-interactive",
        cNounce: "66939",
        cRay: "6d5bfeb08acc8771",
        cHash: "18474546270a019",
        cPMDTk: "wjoavPcyn4sd4H8OTvY2JlyVlLXStFtB1PtHY4IbL58-1643559283-0-gaNycGzNB70",
        cUPMDTk: "\/prod\/Pokemon-Leafeon-V-Star-Special-Collection-Box?__cf_chl_tk=wjoavPcyn4sd4H8OTvY2JlyVlLXStFtB1PtHY4IbL58-1643559283-0-gaNycGzNB70",
        cFPWv: "b",
        cTTimeMs: "1000",
        cRq: {
          ru: "aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuY2hhb3NjYXJkcy5jby51ay9wcm9kL1Bva2Vtb24tTGVhZmVvbi1WLVN0YXItU3BlY2lhbC1Db2xsZWN0aW9uLUJveA==",
          ra: "TW96aWxsYS81LjAgKFdpbmRvd3MgTlQgMTAuMDsgV2luNjQ7IHg2NCkgQXBwbGVXZWJLaXQvNTM3LjM2IChLSFRNTCwgbGlrZSBHZWNrbykgQ2hyb21lLzk3LjAuNDY5Mi45OSBTYWZhcmkvNTM3LjM2IEVkZy85Ny4wLjEwNzIuNzY=",
          rm: "R0VU",
          d: "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",
          t: "MTY0MzU1OTI4My4yOTAwMDA=",
          m: "HvTOqkkdUexOvObprQaK20tiA50EsMdMAUNxBs9a76U=",
          i1: "KnbCImKzNxo3XehPmg6jWg==",
          i2: "oGYSEcaLbEuXjAZsN7GZBg==",
          zh: "JJbyu7T+3hg5jWQCnkKHsP/7REhUTr23SkrwnAaFfjA=",
          uh: "l4HLyhywYXQDOYBGJBbVDnfNOSLbBOqVMJwcpsr3qjc=",
          hh: "8JWW5AsAg62xfggeMY1P1hRpDlpOqO6xoRTKU6X/36Q=",
        }
      }
      window._cf_chl_enter = function(){window._cf_chl_opt.p=1};
      
    })();
    //]]>
  </script>
  

</head>
<body>
  <table width="100%" height="100%" cellpadding="20">
    <tr>
      <td align="center" valign="middle">
          <div class="cf-browser-verification cf-im-under-attack">
  <noscript>
    <h1 data-translate="turn_on_js" style="color:#bd2426;">Please turn JavaScript on and reload the page.</h1>
  </noscript>
  <div id="cf-content" style="display:none">
    
    <div id="cf-bubbles">
      <div class="bubbles"></div>
      <div class="bubbles"></div>
      <div class="bubbles"></div>
    </div>
    <h1><span data-translate="checking_browser">Checking your browser before accessing</span> www.chaoscards.co.uk.</h1>
    
    <div id="no-cookie-warning" class="cookie-warning" data-translate="turn_on_cookies" style="display:none">
      <p data-translate="turn_on_cookies" style="color:#bd2426;">Please enable Cookies and reload the page.</p>
    </div>
    <p data-translate="process_is_automatic">This process is automatic. Your browser will redirect to your requested content shortly.</p>
    <p data-translate="allow_5_secs" id="cf-spinner-allow-5-secs" >Please allow up to 5 seconds&hellip;</p>
    <p data-translate="redirecting" id="cf-spinner-redirecting" style="display:none">Redirecting&hellip;</p>
  </div>
   
  <form class="challenge-form" id="challenge-form" action="/prod/Pokemon-Leafeon-V-Star-Special-Collection-Box?__cf_chl_f_tk=wjoavPcyn4sd4H8OTvY2JlyVlLXStFtB1PtHY4IbL58-1643559283-0-gaNycGzNB70" method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <input type="hidden" name="md" value="lBy7XQRIP3rCTVaX6BoLog981WTI9wl7VPUnFUhdr80-1643559283-0-AfIJze-AsdFTbXwD6zN0kNrMUN92opj5F0JV4HP_IIHIJajx_7BeYxgFsAgzPKKs7B76uy2sTy0NMNe5Lonr5nsHsVd0d8oakLrUtEc43FE_-loi5O9yohJL7zVGcrm5BD3ZjEJMgxY3VwIM0TIl4QifHX3Xiacvm9Us_1J5_OALeEt8dyCDKBUbdhJbfkAV36zEt1-iFbst-6wTI-t_LM6YSJOD9j1K_sxVqdUzAawDadHBGslCDmRO4mA2LTGMhZdNdVN_RUZkUpqWKatfeHID4Hp-w3fx3tW4lxHE6gC86Ud8f-YgeYHKUDkfA_YomWCUxk9WFwoEYlr7MqQhQgWfBgxhAJNpXEbcaIb9e71bSZvbGw8BCLipFXuSk2ZvFofI-CdPIymN17v4S2xNgL92cGpXRhcr1OwJT6iFPJ8zuxPXPGud3C9ZeHnXbntYoYRQFXRcpcYcKIbBJEG8lIhJ4aWqmVkpkmai5oGlf0tnolsiO_5-i8cCEazYlbcUCqKnVDt6UGfuQNJdQXTNmmwNusmt4kPFLztjhNjKydzWHO6AWswLkMzj7rC1759cGdsyBiQkzb632-4Yqvi4f6ZOwBOEWfE0t8ZwdQtkEWy4U84c9j6hM8MG_xgl3t_0yKWRIFANVD9vkN1pqTfJRo8bQPm9oD3KmvRrVl5y_5InKhUotZYMJVV6DhV98WvHVOvjOGqJMPs75vQ0VaqQUiPzlyJ1MQ0G4Qe-sZzoIP0cxuvkCbQE2kxhRrzN887jWQ" />
    <input type="hidden" name="r" value="IxoGI_uynuxxTjqGKlMnSQ0FLUh3S6TIZtjcFTDgzzE-1643559283-0-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"/>
    <input type="hidden" value="b8506ea0b61c6bf512de56146f25f432" id="jschl-vc" name="jschl_vc"/>
    <!-- <input type="hidden" value="" id="jschl-vc" name="jschl_vc"/> -->
    <input type="hidden" name="pass" value="1643559284.29-RM/SqTEMYf"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="jschl-answer" name="jschl_answer"/>
  </form>
     
    <script type="text/javascript">
      //<![CDATA[
      (function(){
          var a = document.getElementById('cf-content');
          a.style.display = 'block';
          var isIE = /(MSIE|Trident\/|Edge\/)/i.test(window.navigator.userAgent);
          var trkjs = isIE ? new Image() : document.createElement('img');
          trkjs.setAttribute("src", "/cdn-cgi/images/trace/jschal/js/transparent.gif?ray=6d5bfeb08acc8771");
          trkjs.id = "trk_jschal_js";
          trkjs.setAttribute("alt", "");
          document.body.appendChild(trkjs);
          var cpo=document.createElement('script');
          cpo.type='text/javascript';
          cpo.src="/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/h/b/orchestrate/jsch/v1?ray=6d5bfeb08acc8771";
          
          window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUQuery = location.search === '' && location.href.indexOf('?') !== -1 ? '?' : location.search;
          window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash = location.hash === '' && location.href.indexOf('#') !== -1 ? '#' : location.hash;
          if (window._cf_chl_opt.cUPMDTk && window.history && window.history.replaceState) {
            var ogU = location.pathname + window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUQuery + window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash;
            history.replaceState(null, null, "\/prod\/Pokemon-Leafeon-V-Star-Special-Collection-Box?__cf_chl_rt_tk=wjoavPcyn4sd4H8OTvY2JlyVlLXStFtB1PtHY4IbL58-1643559283-0-gaNycGzNB70" + window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash);
            cpo.onload = function() {
              history.replaceState(null, null, ogU);
            };
          }
          
          document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(cpo);
        }());
      //]]>
    </script>
  

  
  <div id="trk_jschal_nojs" style="background-image:url('/cdn-cgi/images/trace/jschal/nojs/transparent.gif?ray=6d5bfeb08acc8771')"> </div>
</div>

          
          <div class="attribution">
            DDoS protection by <a rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.cloudflare.com/5xx-error-landing/" target="_blank">Cloudflare</a>
            <br />
            <span class="ray_id">Ray ID: <code>6d5bfeb08acc8771</code></span>
          </div>
      </td>
     
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html> ```` 

One thing that stood out to me is this 
```<h1 data-translate="turn_on_js" style="color:#bd2426;">Please turn JavaScript on and reload the page.</h1>``` So I am using beautiful soup and I have heard it cant handle java script? Is this whats affecting my search? 

Has anyone got tips, or if you may know the answer to my question but would prefer to point me in the correct direction, I would really appreciate it!

Thank You!
`````

Comment: Give us an example of a product you're searching for.  You fetch the top-level page, but you neger use it, and we don't know what searches you're doing.  And, by the way, if you type ".sm xyz", your "split" command will leave the space at the start of the keyword.  You should probably just do `message.content[3:]`.

Comment: Hi Tim, so product example, I have currently up is "Pokemon Leafeon V-Star Special Collection Box" Oh I did not realise it would do that! I will change that now :)

Comment: OK, but that's not what you have to put in the URL.  Have you looked at the web site source code?  The link for that is https://www.chaoscards.co.uk/prod/singles-pokemon/leafeon-vstar-swsh195-jumbo-pokemon-single-promotional-card.  You have to use the exact link.

Comment: Hi Tim, I thought it was the correct link. Perhaps I should look more into the source code to find the correct links. I sssumed there was just one universal link 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found out my problem. as you can see from the update I made on the original post. I was being blocked from accessing the site. This is due to it being a Java script  loaded site, and apparently beautiful soup can’t load Java script .  Therefore I have scraped the code and followed a new tutorial that uses Selenium and now it works perfectly.

For anyone who stumbles across this post with the same issue I will provide a link to the tutorial I followed in hopes it helps you!

Link: https://replit.com/talk/learn/Python-Selenium-Tutorial-The-Basics/148030

Comment: For the record, it is Javascript, not Java.  Two totally unrelated languages.

Comment: Thank you for spotting my mistake will update the post!

Answer (score 0):

You could try turning the source code of the website into a string and do one of the following:

```
website_contents = website_contents.split('<div class="product-detail__content">')[1].split('</div>')
if 'out' in website_contents.lower():
    print('Out of stock!')
else:
    print('In stock!')
```

or

```
if '>Out of stock </' in website_contents:
    print('Out of stock!')
else:
    print('In stock!')
```

Comment: Hi, i have tried your method. now I may be being dumb here, but when I use the top line defining "Website_contents" it throws a error saying "website_contents is a undefined name" what am i missing here? I though the first line is defining website_contents?

Comment: @TLRxADMIN replace website_contents with a variable that contains a string of the website